# How do I use the modulus operator for this program

Tags: c

Thank you everyone that has helped, this is what I have which works but if there is a more sufficient way I would like to know...

#include < stdio.h >

int main() {

int i = 1;

```
for (i = 1; i <= 50; i++)
{
    if (i % 3)
    {
    printf("%d\n", i);
    }
    else if (i <= 50)
    {
        printf("Hello\n");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: We cannot help you with your code if you don't show us what you have so far, and ask a question about where specifically you are stuck with your code.

Comment: The normal choice for a loop with known boundaries is the `for` loop.

Comment: You need to decide whether you're programming in C or C++. The languages are very different.

Answer (score 2):

`M` is a multiple of `N` if and only if `M % N` is zero.
I'm sure you can work out the rest on your own.